# Fire JS event handler always as the last one, regardless of adding order

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

Is there some way to force event handler in JS to fire always as the last one? Say I know that some new event handlers will occur in the future, but I want to be sure that every new handler will be fired before my special one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to wrap your main function in setTimeout function and pass 0 delay, so Javascript engine will add it to its functions stack and execute that function last.

```
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('MAIN Event');
  },0);
})
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('dosmth2');
}) 
document.getElementById("div1").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('dosmth3asd');
})
```

P.s. using many setTimeouts might decrease performance.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: Very glad to hear, best of luck!